# MultiDatePicker count how much does sunday was selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-multidatespicker

How I can count how much was someday clicked on the multi-date picker,
I have a different price for Sunday and I can't figure out how to count how much was some date selected.

```
      jQuery('#pets-date').multiDatesPicker({
                  numberOfMonths: 2,
                  altField: '#selectedDate',
                  minDate: 2,
                  maxPicks: 20,
                  onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    //var day = date.getUTCDay();

                    if (date == '6') {

                    } else {

                    }

                    $('#numberSelected').val($('#pets-date').multiDatesPicker('getDates').length);
                },    
        });
```

How I can count how much time, day Sunday was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.filter()` with the dates returned by `getDates` to get just the sundays, and get the length of that.

```
onSelect: function() {
    var sundays = $(this).multiDatesPicker('getDates', 'object').filter(d => d.getUTCDay() == 6).length;
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I have tryed this code but console log always return 0, i don't understand why?

Comment: Typo, `getUTCDay` should be `getUTCDay()`

Comment: Now im getting TypeError: d.getUTCDay is not a function

Comment: I needed to specify the format to return the dates.

Comment: Works like charm, thank you. Can i ask 1 more question. How you can highlight the selected days, lets say i pick sunday and its add class to all sundays under in the current month.

Comment: Make an array of all the sunday dates in the month, then use the `addDates` method to highlight them all.